# Docusign- While creating through API - Error calling CreateEnvelope. This account lacks sufficient permissions

Tags: docusignapi

I am using a demo account. I have created few users and set them as Docusign senders group. My functionality is to send envelops via API, from these users. This functionality used to work before. Since yesterday it is throwing an error saying as below. 
Its now only working when i send(via API) with Admin User account.I would appreciate if you could assist me on this.

Error calling CreateEnvelope: `{\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS\",\r\n  \"message\": \"This Account lacks sufficient permissions. SigningGroups Disabled\"\r\n}"}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send an envelope to a signing group, but signing groups have been disabled on your account.

If this is a Production environment account, you'll want to reach out to your Account Manager for assistance. If this is in Demo or if you don't have an AM, you'll want to open a Support case.

Comment: Yes, somehow the signing group got disabled and requested AM to enable it. Now its working.
Thank you for the help.